# Substituting field attributes from another document in restructured text + sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am working on some documentation in restructured text using sphinx and want to substitute values defined as fields from one document into another.

Given a file `foo.rst` I would like to use the value of its `Author` field in another document. For instance, it is defined as follows:

```
Foo
===

:Author: Random, Joe;

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ...
```

And I have the following snippet in some other file `bar.rst`

```
In "Foo" <insert author field from foo.rst>
writes ...
```

Once compiled and converted to HTML using sphinx, I want the output of `bar.rst` to be:

```
In "Foo" Random, Joe writes ...
```

I've looked at the documentation and it only [specifies setting fields](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists) and doesn't have anything on accessing these fields from another document.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and add some more code to clarify your code example as well. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way as far as I know, perhaps it depends on the theme you use (look in conf.py item "html_theme = ...").

But you can do this:

in foo.rst:

```
.. _author_random:

:Author: Random, Joe;
```

in bar.rst:

```
:ref:`any text <author_random>`
```

Then you have in bar.html a link to _author_random with the text "any text".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. But this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, though. I want to avoid typing the author name each time I have to refer to them. I'm using the default [readthedocs theme](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I'll try looking into the documentation there.